# Disable caching for subdomain on Cloudflare?

Tags: cache, cdn, cloudflare

How can I disable caching for a subdomain on Cloudflare but keep SSL?

Comment: You can use Page Rules - see:  [How do I exclude a specific URL from Cloudflare's caching?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172316-How-do-I-exclude-a-specific-URL-from-Cloudflare-s-caching-).